# How to get Console.Debug Logs from the HoloLens 2 device

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, debugging, hololens

I've created an HoloLens 2 App and deployed it to the HoloLens 2. The app isn't working properly so I want to see error messages to fix it. In Unity the App works fine. How can I debug my App from the HoloLens 2?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio can help you to deploy and debug your app or even to debug a Universal Windows app that's installed without deploying from a Visual Studio project.

Besides, you should use Unity API [Debug.Log](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.Log.html) to print informational messages and the logs are all displayed in the output window of Visual Studio. For how to do it, please follow this step-by-step guide:[Using Visual Studio to deploy and debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/platform-capabilities-and-apis/using-visual-studio#graphics-debugger-for-hololens-1st-gen)